# Styling selectbox via CSS

Tags: css, select, input

i've got a problem with the styling of a select box via css. It should look like the other in puts in my page. Here is an exmaple of my current code for you.

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" style="width:35px;margin-right:0px;">
<input type="text" style="width:180px;">
```

And here the CSS i use:

```
input[type=text], textarea, select{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  font:10px sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 240px;
  height:14px;
  padding:5px;
    color: #101010;
}
```

Here you can find a fiddle with the problem if got: http://jsfiddle.net/6VGWc/. The selectbox is "invisible". I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but adding a `box-sizing` rule makes the content (the first option of the `select` element) visible:

```
-moz-box-sizing: content-box; /* for Firefox/Gecko browsers */
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* for Webkit-based browsers, Safari, Chrome, Chromium... */
-o-box-sizing: content-box; /* for Opera */
box-sizing: content-box; /* or 'padding-box' or 'border-box' */
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6VGWc/1/).

Please note that styling a `select` box is often difficult to do cross-browser, as they're often simply replaced elements (much like an `img`) supplied/handled by the OS, rather than the browser itself.

If, however, you choose to declare a specific `height` (or `min-height`) to the element this would work, but may be more difficult to manage should your styles ever change subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the select box needs to be set differently to the text boxes.

Setting the height of the select box to `27px` makes it the same height as the text boxes for me.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6VGWc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your height is set too small for the select.  I added

```
select{
height: 27px;
}
```

to your css and it 'appears'.  I surmise you're asking for more.  After it's this height, what  else are you asking for it to look like?